# How to retrieve all objects in a Mongodb collection including the ids?

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah, salat

I'm using [Casbah](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/) and [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat) to create my own Mongodb dao and am implementing a getAll method like this:

```
val dao: SalatDAO[T, ObjectId]    
def getAll(): List[T] = dao.find(ref = MongoDBObject()).toList
```

What I want to know is:

1. Is there a better way to retrieve all objects?
2. When I iterate through the objects, I can't find the object's _id. Is it excluded? How do I include it in the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1°/ The `ModelCompanion` trait provides a `def findAll(): SalatMongoCursor[ObjectType] = dao.find(MongoDBObject.empty)` methods. You will have to do a dedicated request for every collection your database have.

If you iterate over the objects returned, it could be better to iterate with the `SalatMongoCursor[T]` returned by the `dao.find` rather than doing two iterations (one with the `toList` from `Iterator` trait then another on your `List[T]`).

2°/ Salat maps the _id key with your class id field. If you define a class with an `id: ObjectId` field. This field is mapped with the mongo _id key.
You can change this behaviour using the `@Key` annotation as pointed out in [Salat documentation](https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/Annotations)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something like:

`MyDAO.ids(MongoDBObject("_id" -> MongoDBObject("$exists" -> true)))`

This fetches all the ids, but given the wide range of what you might be doing, probably not the best solution for all situations. Right now, I'm building a small system with 5 records of data, and using this to help understand how MongoDB works.

If this was a production database with 1,000,000 entries, then this (or any getAll query) would be stupid. Instead of doing that, consider trying to write a targeted query that goes after the real results you seek.