# How to encapsulate SalatMongoCurser in Salat DAO?

Tags: mongodb, scala, dao, salat

[Here](http://sysgears.com/articles/how-to-build-a-simple-mongodb-dao-in-scala-using-salatdao/) a solution is explained on how to encapsulate database specific `MongoDBObject` when making a call to a salat DAO method. Now if I use the `find` method that returns a `SalatMongoCursor`, my code will again be dependent on the specific database. I see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391911/1545579) that changing the cursor to a list is bad for performance. Is there a better way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having received no reactions so far to my question, I conclude the answer is "No". Personally, I decided to convert to a List because I will need to traverse it several times later anyway.